# Scrollview hide other view content

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am newbie in android. following is my activity xml.

My question is in "linearLayoutTableViews" linear layout, if I add more than 10 buttons, It hide "Select Table" text view. If I add less views (basically which do not fill complete view port) than, I am able to see textview "Select Table". What is the reason for that? And how I can resolve it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSelectTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Select Table"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="70dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTableViews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about using a Relative layout and specify - layout_below property for scrollview??

Comment: whatever you are adding in the `linearLayoutTableViews`. It must be LinearLayout as a parent View . if you using other parent layout ,it will collapse .

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from `TextView` and make  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, this will work:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: But i guess then it will make "Select table" scrollable as well!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have specified weight property for one child view of linear layout.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

while there is no weight specified for other child view(scrollview)

Can you try specifying the same for scrollview as well!

Secondly -
As mentioned - you can use relative layout as an alternative with  layout_below property for scrollview. Not yet tried though!

Comment: try you first . relative layout and frame layout can't be good with the scroll view .

Comment: @sushildlh   May i ask what could be the possible issue?
I understand that Relative layout within a scrollview is not a good option.. but not sure of the other way round!

Comment: that's not the reason, it is a statement but can't be considered as a fact!

Answer (score 0):

Linear Layout computes weights on views after views with fixed size are computed.
Here you have a layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    .
    .
    .
    >

<TextView
    .
    .
    .
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    .
    .
    .
    />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .
    .
    .
    >
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So it subtracts the computed height from the scrollView and then computes weight.

My suggestion. Give the scrollView a weight or a fixed height.It's A ScrollView so if there are any extra items, it will scroll.